# Reformatting tabular data with jq

Tags: json, jq

I have some JSON with structure like

```
{
  "columns": [
    {
      "id": 123,
      "title": "column 1"
    },
    {
      "id": 456,
      "title": "column 2"
    }
  ],
  "rows": [
    {
      "cells": [
        {
          "columnId": 123,
          "value": "foo"
        },
        {
          "columnId": 456,
          "value": "bar"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cells": [
        {
          "columnId": 123,
          "value": "foo1"
        },
        {
          "columnId": 456,
          "value": "bar1"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Each row has a cell for every column and columnId matches id in columns.

How could I get a list of objects looking like:

```
[
{
  'column 1': 'foo',
  'column 2': 'bar'
},
{
  'column 1': 'foo1',
  'column 2': 'bar1'
}
```

Comment: @glennjackman I was copypasting and editing much larger objects but thanks I will fix it to make it easier to get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way that uses [`INDEX`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#SQL-StyleOperators) and `JOIN` to perform the matching, one [`add`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#add) to combine both sides of the match, and another `add` to create the final object (along with two other variants that each omit and compensate for an `add`).

```bash
INDEX(.columns[]; .id) as $map | .rows | map(
  [JOIN($map; .cells[]; "\(.columnId)"; add | {(.title): .value})] | add
# [JOIN($map; .cells[]; "\(.columnId)"; {(last.title): first.value})] | add
# [JOIN($map; .cells[]; "\(.columnId)"; add | .key = .title)] | from_entries
)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/WXCzHq9HMg2)
[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/YKfZBSicr8s)
[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/_7OsqURS_PM)

---

And here's one that combines using `INDEX` with @Glenn's [shorter approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76535273/2158479) to `map` the `.cells` array using [string interpolation](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#Stringinterpolation%3A%5C%28exp%29) to look up the column id in the map:

```bash
INDEX(.columns[]; .id) as $map | .rows | map(
  .cells | map({($map."\(.columnId)".title): .value}) | add
)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/qabXFY2NqDE)

Comment: Same question as to Glenn: Why does `.rows` operate on the entire input instead of just `$map`? I don't get it.

Comment: @chx That's how variable binding works. Look at [Variable / Symbolic Binding Operator `... as $identifier | ...`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Variable%2FSymbolicBindingOperator%3A...as%24identifier%7C...) in the manual. The pipe is part of the syntax, and the follow-up context is the one before that whole construct (thus, ignoring the "inner" pipe) but with the variable binding visible afterwards.

Comment: That's really not clear :/ let's make it explicit: https://github.com/jqlang/jq/pull/2627

Comment: @chx Think of it like `as` does not alter the context, it just binds (possibly a subset of) it to a variable. Just like with using parentheses, you can dive into the structure, maybe even modifying it, but afterwards the context is restored. Try `[1,2,3,4,5] | (.[] | select(. % 2 == 0)) = 10` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/eoIl5RkzdKg): The array is still there, even though we descended into its items using `.[]` (not `map`!), but it happened inside parentheses. That way you can think of variable bindings as using parens to refine the value. Pseudo code: `$var ← (.items[].get | select(filter))`

Answer (score 1):

This works, but it's pretty messy

```bash
jq '
  (.columns | map({(.id | tostring): .title}) | add) as $columnTitles
  | .rows | map(
      .cells | map({($columnTitles[.columnId | tostring]): .value}) | add
    )
' file.json
```

```json
[
  {
    "column 1": "foo",
    "column 2": "bar"
  },
  {
    "column 1": "foo1",
    "column 2": "bar1"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks! Let me ask: why do we need toString here?

Comment: JSON object keys must be strings. https://www.json.org